# How can I use spatial heterogeneity within regions as predictors about those regions?

Tags: dataset, heteroscedasticity, spatial, aggregation

Please forgive if I am misusing the term "spatial heterogeneity". I am trying to predict county level crop productivity using satellite acquired vegetative health (NDVI). Since this is pixel data, I have to aggregate the data into a mean or median, but I end up losing all the diversity of values at the pixel level. In fact, I think this NDVI diversity within the county has some predictive power.

How can I represent this county-level spatial heterogeneity or diversity as a useful predictor variable? In essence I believe the county mean NDVI is stripping away valuable information about the distribution of NDVI within the county itself, and I want to use it to help my yield prediction. Thanks very much for your interest and help!

[image: County Level NDVI standard deviation, correlating with Yield]

I am attempting to model and predict county yields using cubist: a rule based regression tree algorithm. Cubist will generate hundreds of multiple regressions. Cubist will incorporate my county aggregated NDVI as part of if/then rules to determine which multiple regression to use, and as predictor variables in my models. It might be worth noting that cubist is robust against correlated covariates, and I'll link to the guide right here: 
https://www.rulequest.com/cubist-info.html

Comment: From what I understood, I think you may be able to use pixel data (instead of country data). Afterwards, you may also compare some statistics that may interesting to you, such as mean, standard deviation or slopes of regressions.

Comment: Welcome to CV arthur rosales Paying attention to variance as substantively important is a smart move. However, you have not said *anything* about how you are making predictions (although you mention 'variables'), which means your question will likely be voted closed for being to unclear. (You can edit it with the button at lower left.) Assuming you have some form of multiple regression model for predictions, what is wrong with including the mean *and* standard deviation (or range, trimmed range, or IQR) of pixel values in your model?

Comment: @Alexis, thanks for the input, I hope I improved my question properly. My intuition is to include standard deviation and first stabs at it reduce RMSE of my predictions. I guess I'm having a hard time finding a justification for using standard deviation as a predictor variable: it feels like a faux pas and I'm not finding many examples where it's used in this way. I haven't considered ranges and will try. Thanks!

Comment: "it feels like a faux pas" embrace your naughtiness.

Comment: I just wanted to add this question to the discussion: asked in 2015 but no answers. Basically a very similar scenario, wondering if standard deviation is appropriate for this within-territory variability https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/157765/262651

Comment: Using the moments (standard deviation, skew) of a predictor variable is totally valid.  All you need to do to justify it is think whether it is plausible that overall country crop yield would be influenced by it.  To me seems sensible, imagine two counties with the same mean NVDI but one county where NVDI is pretty much equal everywhere, and one where it is really high in some places and really low in others.  

You could in principle derive any covariates you think might matter (e.g. % area with NDVI > some threshold).  There's nothing to stop you!  Just what you think matters for your Q